# Restoring Rotation In Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using Three.js and I want to be able to take an object from the scene and then replace it with a new object but at the same rotation as the one I removed.

I take note of the rotation of the object I am removing and then use this function to set the rotation on the new object:

```
rotateToWorldAxis  = function(object, xradians, yradians, zradians)  {
  axisX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
  axisY = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
  axisZ = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

  rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  rotationMatrix.setRotationAxis(axisX.normalize(), xradians)
  object.matrix = rotationMatrix;
  object.rotation.setRotationFromMatrix(object.matrix);

  rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  rotationMatrix.setRotationAxis(axisY.normalize(), yradians);
  rotationMatrix.multiplySelf(object.matrix);
  object.matrix = rotationMatrix;
  object.rotation.setRotationFromMatrix(object.matrix);

  rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  rotationMatrix.setRotationAxis(axisZ.normalize(), zradians);
  rotationMatrix.multiplySelf(object.matrix);
  object.matrix = rotationMatrix;
  object.rotation.setRotationFromMatrix(object.matrix);
}
```

The x and y rotations work just fine but the z rotation does not give the desired result.

I would be very grateful if someone could spot what I am doing wrong or maybe I should be doing it another way ?

Thanks

Comment: The code you have posted is completely wrong on many levels. Did you try the single line: `object.rotation.set( xradians, yradians, zradians )`, where `xradians = oldObject.rotation.x`, etc.?

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply - I took your suggestion and changed the function to:

    rotateToWorldAxis  = function(object, xradians, yradians, zradians)  {
      object.rotation.set(xradians, yradians, zradians);
      object.matrix.setRotationFromEuler(object.rotation);
    }

And now it works just fine - thanks again !

Comment: You do not need the `setRotationFromEuler()` part. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
object.rotation.set( xradians, yradians, zradians );
```

where `xradians = oldObject.rotation.x`, etc...

Also, unless you have changed it, the default value for `object.matrixAutoUpdate` is `true`, so you do not need to set the `object.matrix` directly. -- just set the rotation. The `render()` call will update the matrix for you.

Comment: It can also be simplified to.... `oldRotation.copy( oldObject.rotation ); object.copy( oldRotation );`

Comment: @mrdoob, did you mean `object.rotation.copy( oldObject.rotation );`? That IS better. I don't understand your second expression, though...

Comment: Ah, yes yes. That's even better.